# Add value without using index in 2D arrayList inside a HashMap, Java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I'm fairly new to ArrayLists anyway but I need them for this simulation project I'm doing so if you guys could help me I would be more than grateful!

I have a HashMap of 2D arrayLists which should be filled with "value" and "time" in every iteration of simulation based on a String key. I define my variable as follow:

```
protected Map<String, ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>> history = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>>();
```

, and I initialize it like this:

```
for (String act:keySet)  
   history.put(act, new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>());
```

Every ArrayList of my Map has two arrayList, and in every iteration I should add my "value", and "time" in every arrayList, so I can store my data and its respective time together, but I don't know how to use key, call my arraylist without using index like in normal arrayList when we can do like this:

```
tmpData.add("foobar"); // Example
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Vahid

Comment: what do you mean by `Every ArrayList of my Map has two arrayList`?

Comment: I mean I have arrayList of two arraylists one for "value", one for "Time".

Comment: you better rephrase the question, or add an example to clarify what you want, I get the map part, and the ArrayList that Will contain two ArrayLists, but what I don't get is what will those two array lists contain.

Comment: so basically `ArrayList<Object>` is always of size `2`, is that what you are saying?

Comment: Sorry for confusion fellas! My Hash Map contains String keys and  arrayLists, and every arraylist is actually 2D which is supposed to store 2 value in which is "time" and corresponding "value" so my HashMap is like  "data1", {{0,1},{1,3},{3,-10},...}. "data2",{{0,-4},{1,3},{2,12},...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected Map<String, ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>> history = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>>();
    Double time=null;
    Double value=null;
    time2=null;
    ArrayList <Double> inner=null;
    for (String act:keySet){
      ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> outer=null;
      if ((outer=history.get(act))==null)
      {
         outer= new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> ();
      }
       inner=new ArrayList <Double>();
       time= value1;//your value for this integer 
       value= value2;
       inner.add(time);
       inner.add(value);
       outer.add(inner);

       history.put(act, outer);
       }
```

in each iteration we check if the map contains that key, if it does we we add a new we fill the inner ArrayList with new time objecs, and we add it to the preexisted outer ArrayList then we update the value of the outer ArrayList associated with that key, if it doesn't contain that key we create outer map, inner map, and time objects fill the inner ArrayList, outer ArrayList, associate the outer ArrayList with the key.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: that answer is based on what I understood, I am not sure whether it met your requirements or not, so did it ?

Comment: I have an error using this code. What is Time class in here? Is it in fact time1 which has been defined earlier?

Comment: oh I thought your inner ArrayList contained objects of time class that you created.

Comment: No, my inner arrayList contains, my "Time" and "Value" as double numbers to be stored. In this case could you please help me with that?

Comment: @vahidkhoshdel  do you get what I am trying to achieve here ? I am sure that you have to some changes to the code above in order for it to work exactly as you want, if you need any help I am available.

Comment: Thanks QuakeCore. Changed your code and worked for me like a charm!!

Comment: hehe anytime, now if you Don't mind marking this answer as correct, so that the others can tell that this was a useful answer, I would appreciate it so much :)